# What does this "merely" imply?

Tags: grammar

> She had no hatred against the **merely** vulgar traits of his.

This is a stand-alone sentence from my grammar workbook.
But the nuance of merely here is strange to me.

Comment: It could be re-sequenced (with small syntactic adjustments) as She had no hatred against [those] traits of his [which were] merely *vulgar* (as opposed to, say, traits he might have which were *aggressive, threatening*). With just the one sentence it's ambiguous whether he has other traits (apart from the vulgar ones) which she *does* hate.

Comment: If it's a stand-alone sentence from a grammar workbook it's unknowable/irrelevant whether there were other traits that she actually hated.

Answer (score 1):

"*Merely* vulgar traits" implies that there he had traits which were more sinister. I like the phrase; very literary, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's an adverb modifying the significance of the word vulgar, it's reducing the vulgarity of his traits. Personally, it seems a little opposing in idea, but certainly possible.

Comment: Perhaps even used as an idea of 'insignificant' vulgar traits?

Comment: the point is there were other traits she hated more?

Comment: Perhaps not at all, maybe she just found them unimportant in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

> She had no hatred against the merely vulgar traits of his.

Here **merely** refers to **only** (no better than what is specified) that means She doesn't hate against only vulgar traits of his but there is something else for which she hates.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments from FumbleFingers say, it's a little ambiguous as to whether he has other traits which are worse than "mere" vulgarity, which she does hate, or whether she is indifferent to *his* traits (which are merely vulgar), and hates *someone else's* more sinister/malicious traits -- or if she was expected to hate his vulgar traits but only dislikes them or is indifferent to them.

However, since the phrasing is "the merely vulgar traits of his," that focus on the "*traits* of his" in the sentence structure implies (at least to me) that there are other traits of his that go beyond mere vulgarity into something hateful.

...in the end, though, it's a standalone, and the "merely" is modifying "vulgar" -- the traits under consideration are nothing but vulgar, rather than malicious, sinister, sadistic, or otherwise more deliberately unpleasant.